# Is it a nice way to declare common attributes in a super class and later extend it in other classes...?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some attributes like createdDate, createBy, modifiedDate, modifiedBy, deletedDate, deletedBy that are common in most of the POJO's.

Can I declare these attributes in a super class and later extend it in other classes...??

Comment: Post the code that you have tried before coming here please.

Comment: What do you mean by "extend"? Do you mean read and modify fields in a sub class (as in `protected` access)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone explained this is perfectly valid from inheritance view. Since you have added hibernate tag, what is your intention about the columns in the database? 
Do you need these attributes to be present in a common parent table or you want to add these attributes in each individual table.
You need to choose the right inheritance strategy using
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType)
or you can also consider having a mapped super class without its own database table. You can annotate such class with @MappedSuperclass annotation.

Regards
Asheesh

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I don't see why you didn't at least try it on your own though.

```
public class Base {
    protected Date createdDate;
    public Base() {
        createDate = new Date();
    }
}

public class SubClass extends Base {
    public SubClass() {
        // you can access createdDate here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. But you need to be careful.

Because in such cases overriding equals and hashcode becomes almost mandatory in cases these fields contribute significantly to equality.
And there are also some side effects of it as mentioned [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=joshua%20bloch%20composition%20over%20inheritance&source=bl&ots=yZGfMlq2P1&sig=qqcPhmzHhGPk_cn-_n9YreHaWRs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIl-evi6bDxwIV0m2OCh1ccADz)